# GRE Quantitative problem on distributions

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, gre-exam

I was doing some problems on [this](https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_GRE_pb_revised_general_test.pdf) .Can some one please help me with the following:

[image]

Here the given answer is that quantity B is grater than Quantity A. How is this obtained? Do we know anything  about the two distributions whether they are normal or what?

Also in the question

[image]

how is the answer obtained? Is it by plugging in various values?

Answer (score 1):

Answer on 15.

(A) If $x>0$ then inequality $\frac53x<x$ would allow us to conclude that $$\frac53<1$$ (dividing by positive $x$ is permitted and does not change the sign) which is not true.

So it cannot have positive solutions.

(B) We can rewrite this as $$x(x-1)(x+1)<0$$ Then $x$ is a solution of it if it makes an odd number of these $3$ factors negative and makes the others positive. Can you find a positive $x$ that does that? Can you find a negative $x$ doing so as well?

(C) if $x$ would be a solution of this inequality then: $$-6<-7$$ (found by subtraction of $x$ on both sides) which is not true.

So the inequality has no solutions at all.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Can you please tell me how the question 1 is done?

Comment: Notice that you ask two questions that do not have *any* relation to each other. That is not good practice. If you want an answer on the other question then delete it here and ask it as a new question.